# The method is showing the entire code and [decompiled] is displayed beside the Class name in visual studio

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have created a nuget package with some basic logic and uploded into nuget site. Later i created a test project and then used the newly created nuget package in the test project.

When i click on 'Go to Definition' on the method, then it is navigating to the installed package and showing the entire code rather than just the definitions. Also it shows [decomplied] beside the class name.

[image]

How to make sure to not show the entire code of a Class?

Comment: Why do you want it not to show the source? For security point of view or for some other reasons?